# Get response JSON object webservice RESTful java

Tags: java, json, web-services, tomcat, restful-architecture

When I access my URL http://localhost:8081/projectName/pathh/param to show me the JSON Object created

```
"Employee": [{
    "id": "param"
}]
```

This is my code in Java. I use Eclipse + Tom Cat Server.

```
@Path("/pathh")
@GET
    @Path("{parameter}")

    public Response getJSONObj(@PathParam("parameter") String parameter) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();

        jsonObj.put("id", parameter);
        jsonarray.put(jsonObj);
        System.out.println(jsonarray);
        JSONObject jsonMain = new JSONObject();
        jsonMain.put("Employee", jsonarray);
        System.out.println(jsonMain.toString());
        System.out.println(Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain).build());
        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain).build();
        }
```

I get that error :

> HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of
>   arguments
>
> type Exception report
>
> message java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

Comment: Do you have two `@Path` annotations in the same method?

Comment: Yes, I have that annotation.. Everything is alright on debug mode, but the line with the return it seems to have some bugs..

Comment: I found the problem..I should have put the toString() method  after jsonarray return Response.status(200).entity(jsonarray.toString()).build();

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.tests;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
@Path("/path/{parameter}")

public class Test1 {
    @GET
   public Response getJSONObj(@PathParam("parameter") String parameter) {

        JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray jsonarray = new JsonArray();

        jsonObj.addProperty("id", parameter);
        jsonarray.add(jsonObj);
        System.out.println(jsonarray);
        JsonObject jsonMain = new JsonObject();
        jsonMain.add("Employee", jsonarray);
        System.out.println(jsonMain.toString());
        System.out.println(Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain).build());
        return Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain.toString()).build();
        }
```

}

I have used Jersey as the Jax-RS API implementation. jersey-server and jersey-servlet are included as dependencies and web.xml has an entry for the jersey servlet mapping.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could debug it and find the line it's failing on, or whether it never makes it into the method and you have a problem with your application wiring/annotations.

That said, I suspect that if you delete or comment out the line

```
System.out.println(Response.status(200).entity(jsonMain).build());
```

it will work.